# iOS Switch statement not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement

I've got a View Controller with five buttons. Each button should trigger a modal segue to a different view controller based on the tag of the button, represented by declared constants:

```
- (IBAction)aButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self buttonForSegue:sender];
}

-(void) buttonForSegue:(UIButton *)sender
{

    switch ([sender tag])
    {
        case aVsAButton_tag:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"aVsAModal" sender:self];
            break;
        case cVsCButton_tag:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"cVsCModal" sender:self];
            break;
        case actVsAllButton_tag:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"actVsAllModal" sender:self];
            break;
        case catVsAllButton_tag:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"catVsAllModal" sender:self];
            break;
        case customDatePickerButton_tag:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"customDatePickerModal" sender:self];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Regardless of which button I hit, the app crashes in the sim with this message (only the button names change):

**2014-02-10 19:11:47.305 WMDGx[24366:a0b] -[ReportViewController aVsAllButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a911e0
2014-02-10 19:11:47.307 WMDGx[24366:a0b] * ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ReportViewController aVsAllButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a911e0'**

My code looks reasonable to me, but apparently not. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This issue has nothing to the your switch statement. The crash is telling you the specific problem. You are calling selector on your `ReportViewController` that it doesn't respond to. You'll need to show the code where the `aVsAllButton:` selector is being called.

Comment: @Jeremy--Duncan C nailed it in the second answer. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're reporting would not be caused by the code you posted. I'm guessing that you have an IBAction link in your buttons and that action method no longer exists. Open your storyboard file, select the scene for your view controller, and use the connections inspector to check the action link for each button. You may need to break the connection and re-link it to the proper IBAction.

Comment: Bingo! I had more than one connection on each button. I'd forgotten them from an earlier iteration trying to hook each button individually to a segue. Many thanks, an up vote and an accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has nothing to do with your switch statement, but rather calling a function that doesn't exist on one of your controllers.

Which line of code does it fail on? Entering the buttonForSegue? At the start of the switch? during one of the performSegueWithIdentifier?

Things you can try:

- Ensure that sender is actually a UIButton class
- Ensure that the tag is set on the button
- Check the view controller that you are seguing to implements the method `aVsAllButton`

Comment: See Duncan C's answer below for specific solution. Thanks for responding!